# C# Interface without static typing

Tags: c#

Is there way to do something along these lines?

```
interface Iface
{
  [anytype] Prop1 { get; }
  [anytype] Prop2 { get; }
}

class Class1 : Iface
{
  public string Prop1 { get; }
  public int Prop2 { get; }
}

class Class2 : Iface
{
  public int Prop1 { get; }
  public bool? Prop2 { get; }
}
```

I don't care about the type of the properties, I just need the properties to be available.  This doesn't have to be implemented with an interface, just using that as an example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Make the interface generic:**

```
interface Iface<T1,T2>
{
   T1 Prop1  { get; }
   T2 Prop2  { get; }
}
```

**Alternatively, make the properties of type `object`:**

```
interface Iface
{
   object Prop1  { get; }
   object Prop2  { get; }
}
```

**If you're using .NET 4.0 you could even make the properties of type `dynamic`:**

```
interface Iface    {
   dynamic Prop1  { get; }
   dynamic Prop2  { get; }
}
```

Comment: Neither of those would actually achieve what's being asked for a with good reason. Iface<String,Int> wouldn't be equivalent to Iface<Int,String>.

Comment: @Lazarus: If the OP expects different classes to implement *the same interface* but allow the fields to vary by type, then only the second and third options would support that. If, however, the OP is looking for a means to simply declare properties with certain names (and ignore the type) then it may still serve some purpose. Overall, it's an unusual requirement for interfaces to begin with.

Comment: The `dynamic` version has no need to be generic.

Comment: @LBushkin: Nice solutions, the whole premise just has a nasty code-smell to me... but it takes all sorts I guess :) Thanks for the explanation. +1

Comment: Agreed Lazarus, what I was trying to do was pretty bad, found what I believe to be a much better way to accomplish my goals.  On the bright side I learned some good things from these responses.  Thanks all :)

Answer (score 5):

use `object`, or a generic `Iface<TValue1,TValue2>`

Answer (score 3):

You would have to either use object or provide a generic interface.

The generic version would look like:

```
interface IFace<T1, T2>
{
   T1 Prop1 { get; }
   T2 Prop1 { get; }
}
```

This will let the implementing type give those properties whatever type it wants, but the downside is that whenever you accept the interface you need to specify those two types:

```
public void DoSomething(IFace<int, string> sadFace)
...
```

This is usually problematic, very limiting at least, it can be "solved" by giving the interface a base interface where both properties are available with `object` return types.

I think the best solution, short of rethinking your approach is to define an interface IFace:

```
interface IFace
{
   object Prop1 { get; }
   object Prop1 { get; }
}
```

Then in your class implement the interface *explicitly* like so:

```
class MyClass: IFace
{
   public string Prop1 { get; }
   public int Prop2 { get; }

   object IFace.Prop1 { get; }
   object IFace.Prop1 { get; }
}
```

This will allow users who know the object is of type `MyClass` to refer to `Prop1` and `Prop2` by their actual types and anything using `IFace` can use the properties with a return type of `object`.

Myself I've used something looking like the last bit of code, and even the "generic interface with base interface" version above, but that was a very specialized scenario and I don't know if I could've solved it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

That rather defeats the objective of an Interface and would violate the strict typing of C#, not even a dynamic would help you out there I fear. The answer is no I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you could do:

```
interface Iface<TType1, TType2>
{ 
  TType1 Prop1 { get; } 
  TType2 Prop2 { get; } 
}
```

However, then `Iface<string, int>` and `IFace<int, bool?>` would be distinct types. (i.e, your `Class1` & `Class2` would not have a common interface)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your usage scenario, but you can sort of do this by implementing the interface explicitly. Note: Your current implementation leaves you no way to assign values to these properties, so you probably want to add a private or protected set accessor to the class properties.

```
interface Iface
{
  object Prop1 { get; }
  object Prop2 { get; }
}

class Class1 : Iface
{
  public string Prop1 { get; }
  public int Prop2 { get; }

  object Iface.Prop1
  {
      get { return Prop1; }
  }

  object Iface.Prop2
  {
      get { return Prop2; }
  }      
}

class Class2 : Iface
{
  public int Prop1 { get; }
  public bool? Prop2 { get; }

  object Iface.Prop1
  {
      get { return Prop1; }
  }

  object Iface.Prop2
  {
      get { return Prop2; }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use object.
If you can provide a scenario where it's being used, people can give better answers.